# Navigating between ViewControllers in SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, navigation, viewcontroller

Im trying to navigate from one view controller to another view controller. Below is the code i used, it doesn't seem to work for me. Doesn't throw an error either.

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainController") as ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

I need help in solving this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is your main view controller embedded in a navigation controller? if not then the optional value navigationContoller? of self will be nil. if it is embedded, can you check at runtime if the self.navigationController? has a value?

Comment: Its not embedded in navigationController. I solved myself. I replaced second line with "            self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: {})".

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah yes that would work too. Glad you figured it out